# VideoWriter output to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, opencv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am creating a web application that makes animation from frames. I use opencv and VideoWriter to implement it. But there is a problem. I want to host my application on Google App Engine, so I cannot save files on it. Is it possible to output the VideoWriter video to Google Cloud Store directly, without saving it on the machine, or I must find other library to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, [streaming transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) are supported by Cloud Storage for other languages, but for Python, or Ruby. [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/about/) has C++, Python, Java and MATLAB interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Android and Mac OS. In other words, if you don't plan to use the Python, or Ruby library version, your setup should work.

Comment: The problem is I plan to use python

Comment: You may consider opening a related feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) to be evaluated and possibly implemented.